# Java 8 Lambdas vs Self-executing Functions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, lambda, java-8, functional-programming

In JavaScript, there's the common pattern of creating an anonymous function and immediately invoking it.

Which is called a [*Self-executing anonymous function*](http://markdalgleish.com/2011/03/self-executing-anonymous-functions/) or an [*immediately-invoked function expression*](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/#iife).

With Java 8 lambdas, is there a standard way to replicate this behavior?

Something like (*pseudocode*):

```
(() -> doSomething())()
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24290803/self-executing-java-methods) asks basically the same question, but for Java 7. I'm explicitly looking for constructs which utilize lambdas.

Comment: in java7 , there was anonymous classes

Comment: [Check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24290939/5050667)

Comment: @asteriskNinja a lambda *is* an anonymous class, just with shorter syntax.

Comment: @OrangeDog don't lambdas handle scope differently?

Comment: @Holger that's the meaning of *is* that I was using.

Comment: @Holger No, lambdas are _not_ implemented as inner classes.

Comment: @Brian Goetz: I didn’t say **inner** classes. I just said **anonymous** classes…

Comment: @Holger While technically correct, when you say "anonymous classes", 99.999% of the Java ecosystem hears "anonymous class" as defined by the language (i.e., "anonymous inner classes") -- very very few people know what VM-anonymous classes are -- and those who do, probably already know how lambdas are implemented.  So, saying "they are implemented using anonymous classes" is guaranteed to confuse anyone who doesn't already know the actual story.  Given that you were responding to OD, who almost certainly is thinking "anonymous inner class", makes it even more likely that you'll confuse.

Comment: @Brian Goetz: I removed that comment, but that doesn’t improve the situation. Comments aren’t the right place to discuss such things. Besides that, I don’t see a real issue with that, as the biggest difference is not whether they are “inner classes”, which is a language level concept only, but that they are not compiler generated class files lying on your disk. Given the popularity of the “curly brace initialization” anti-pattern, developers don’t seem to care about the number of these files anyway…

Comment: @Holger By all means feel free to take the discussion offline -- you should know how to reach me.  My goal here is in not encouraging the myth that lambdas are "just" sugar for inner classes.  They're semantically different (e.g., scoping rules), they're more efficient and optimizable, and they interact with other language features differently (e.g., type inference.)  And yet the "lambdas are just inner classes" myth pervades.  The name `defineAnonymousClass` was unfortunately ambigous; in this context, saying "anonymous class" at all invariably plays into this pervasive and unhelpful myth.

Comment: @Brian Goetz: you don’t need to tell me. Not only the name “`defineAnonymousClass`” is unfortunate, even within the `LambdaMetaFactory` framework, the classes are named “*inner classes*”, see `InnerClassLambdaMetafactory` and source lines like `Class<?> innerClass = spinInnerClass();`. But the myth doesn’t stem from these things. It also doesn’t spread on SO. There are enough developers jumping in, if someone tries to claim that.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Not without declaring the type as well. Since Java is a statically-typed language, and functions are not first class citizens, the compiler needs to know what *type* your lambda is. A function can't just be free-floating, it always needs to be associated with either a class or an instance of a class.

```
Runnable r = () -> {
    System.out.println("Hello world!");
};
r.run();
```

**But:** You can cast the lambda to the `Runnable` type, and give the compiler a hint as to what kind of `@FunctionalInterface` you're implementing:

```
((Runnable)() -> {
    System.out.println("Hello world!");
}).run();
```

Or without the braces, which makes it a one-liner:

```
((Runnable)() -> System.out.println("Hello world!")).run();
```

I imagine that's about as close as you'll get!

Comment: Does usage of Runnable inherently come with a new thread (the Runnable javadoc seems to be pretty focussed on threads), or will this simply execute the code in the current thread?

Comment: @Aljoscha Meyer: `Runnable` is just an interface, like any other.

Comment: There is support for doing it without the need to specify a target type: `{ System.out.println("Hello world!"); }` or without curly braces: `System.out.println("Hello world!");`

Comment: Haha @Holger yes, but OP specifically wanted a solution including a lambda. For whatever reason.

Comment: I agree with Holger, but my "whatever reason" is pretty specific: It involves a framework relying on code generation which only allows me to insert code as arguments to a method invocation. And I can insert a self-executing Supplier lambda-expression to do some calculations on the fly.

Comment: @Aljoscha Meyer: this doesn’t make any sense. The “self executing lambda” shown here, is an expression, just like the encapsulated method invocation, but it still returns `void`, so it’s inapplicable for a method argument. If, however, the function evaluates to a value, the encapsulated expression does as well, so you could use the original expression instead. Well, I hope that framework is worth developing under such strange restrictions…

Comment: The lambda allows me to use multiple lines of code. For one-liners, the lambda is unecessary, that's right. But the lamda was the easiest way I could think of to do some computations which need more than one statement.

Answer (score 2):

What about something like

```
((Runnable)(() -> System.out.println("Foobar"))).run();
```

Comment: You could remove one brace-pair.

Answer (score 0):

Java is very different from JavaScript. And Lambda expressions in Java are not the same as Arrow functions in JavaScript.

Java 8 functions which can be expressed as Lambda expressions or Method references **should conform** to a so-called *Functional interface*, they can't appear out of nowhere. On the contrary, in JavaScript and TypeScript any behavior can be implemented using Arrow functions.

It's important to keep in mind this difference there's no special type for Java 8 Function, that's why we need *Functional interfaces*, which are interfaces having a single abstract method. And Lambdas (as well as Method references) are meant to provide an implementation to this interface).

Lambda expressions and Method references ***have no type by itself*** (*that's a direct consequence of the absence of a Functional type in the Language*).

The expressions give no clue to the compiler about their type:

```
() -> System.out.println("foo")
i -> i * i
```

Both Lambda expressions and Method references are so-called [***poly expressions***](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.2), which means they sensitive to the context in which they appear.

And since Lambdas in have no type by itself and compiler **always** needs to infer their type based on either:

- Assignment context;
- Invocation context;
- Casting context.

Here's a short quote from the [Java Language Specification §15.27. Lambda Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27)

> It is a **compile-time error** if a **lambda expression occurs** in a program in **someplace other than** an ***assignment context*** (§5.2), an ***invocation context*** (§5.3), or a ***casting context*** (§5.5).

In case *Assignment context*, the type specified on the left of the assignment expression tells the compiler what should be the target of the *Functional interface* to which lambda conforms:

```java
Supplier<String> summer = () -> "fooBar";
Runnable r = () -> doSomething(); // this::doSomething
```

Here's a few examples of how to provide a *Casting context* (both statements below are valid):

```java
((Runnable) () -> doSomething()).run();

((Supplier<String>)() -> "FooBar").get().codePoints()
    .filter(Character::isUpperCase)
    .mapToObj(i -> (char) i)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

And here's an illustration of how [target type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html#target_types) can be provided through the *Invocation context*:

```java
String str = (() -> "FooBar").get();         // would Not compile
String str = supplier(() -> "FooBar").get(); // works fine
```

`supplier()`:

```
public static <T> Supplier<T> supplier(Supplier<T> s) {
    return s;
}
```