# Self Executing Anonymous Functions with Lambdas for autogenerated code

Tags: java, function

There's allready a question about it but the answers deals with `Runnable` and not `Function`.
[Self Executing Anonymous Functions via Lambdas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38122121/self-executing-anonymous-functions-via-lambdas)

In this case I need a self executing function that takes an argument and returns a result.
This kind of code is useful to compute values in autogenerated code with holes.

I tried with this syntax:

```
Integer l = ((Function<String,Integer>)(str) -> {
    System.out.println(str);
    return str.length();
}).apply("Hello world Function!");
```

But I get a compilation error:

> error: cannot find symbol

I can't see what is wrong in this syntax.
Any idea how to write such a self executing code?

Comment: i dont get any error. recheck

Comment: it's running fine , got no errors

Comment: About closing, the other post is about Runnable which is not a Function so please keep this post alive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missing symbol errors usually occurs due to missing imports. For this code you need to import the Function interface from the java.util.function package:

```
import java.util.function.Function;
```

Do that and the code will run fine. see [this example](https://ideone.com/q4IaHP).

Comment: I would rather import `java.util.function.Function`, not the whole package?

Comment: Ok, as I'm in autogenerated code I don't think I can import a package.